# Create new command based on an existing one, but with certain characters escaped

Tags: macros

I have to escape underscores very frequently inside `\texttt`, because I use it to mark functions and variables.

I'd like to redefine `\texttt`, under different name, so I could write `\mycommand{my_variable_name}` instead of `\texttt{my\_variable\_name}`.

Comment: `\verb!my_variable_name!` does the same ;-)

Comment: Do you plan to have spaces in the argument to `\mycommand`? Or just strings of plain characters and `_`?

Comment: @egreg I do not plan to have spaces but it'd be nice to have.

Answer (score 5):

You are done with

```
\newcommand{\myvar}[1]{%
  \texttt{\detokenize{#1}}%
}
```

provided you load `fontenc` with the `T1` option. Otherwise you need category code changes, which make the command not suitable to be in the argument to another command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\myvar}[1]{%
  \texttt{\detokenize{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

Here is a variable \myvar{my_variable_name} and also
in a description
\begin{description}
\item[\myvar{my_variable_name}] is a nice variable
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is `\detokenize{#1}` the core part of the solution? What does `T1` mean?

Comment: @Luke Yes, `\detokenize` is the key; `T1` is a font encoding where printable ASCII characters appear as themselves, contrary to what happens with the default OT1 encoding.

Comment: Does it mean I won't be able to write math equations in the same document?

Comment: @Luke Why? There's no reason to worry about math.

Comment: "printable ASCII characters appear as themselves" I guess I didn't get that part.

Comment: @Luke For historical reasons, if you try that without `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` you *might* get a dot instead of `_` (but not with a typewriter font).

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use verbatim mode, i.e. `\verb!my_name!` -- this is output always as `\texttt` or use `xparse` and define a command with verbatim argument 'v', but this macro can't be used in another macro.

This works with spaces too.

Note: The `\begingroup...\endgroup` is to prevent the leaking of `\ttfamily` to the following text.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{+v}{%
  \begingroup
  \ttfamily #1%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\verb!my_variable_name!

\mycommand{my_variable_name}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work inside `\item`: `\begin{description}
...
\item[\verb!abc(d_e, e_f)!] -- blah, blah
\end{description}`

Comment: @Luke: That's what I wrote: You can't use neither of them in another macro. And your question did not contain `\item` ...